# Need help converting machine code

Tags: binary, mips

I would appreciate some help with this question.

The 32 bit numbers below represent a MIPS instruction. identify the different fields and state which instruction it is. give the assembler source code that can be converted into this instruction.

001000|10001|10010|0000000000001111

I separated the bits and I know the first 6 bits are the opcode and given the opcode it means Addi. The last 16 bits are the immediate value which I have converted to 15. I do need help with the registers and converting the binary into the register number. I have looked everywhere and can not find an explanation. Any help would be appreciated. i know the structure takes this format:

Addi, t,s, 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've basically got the answer already: the *s* register is number `0b10001` = 17, the *t* register is number `0b10010` = 18.

The instruction is not quite the way you've said it: standard MIPS has the registers in the opposite order, so it's `opcode rs rt immediate`. The opcode is `0b001000` = 8 = `ADDI`; `rs` is `0b10001` = 17 = `$s1`; `rt` is `0b10010` = 18 = `$s2`; the immediate value is `0b0000000000001111` = 15.

(The prefix `0b` indicates that the following number is in binary.)

Comment: Thank you. i haven't been able to find an information on it. would i need to write $t17?

Comment: @jessie For the registers? For e.g. register 17 you can either use `$17` or `$s1` (its symbolic name).

Comment: is there an efficient way to convert say r17 to its symbolic name $s1?

Comment: @jessie Looking it up in a table is the easiest way. [This one](http://www.cs.uwm.edu/classes/cs315/Bacon/Lecture/HTML/ch05s03.html) was the first hit on Google.

Comment: Thank you. this will help with my studies. can i ask if i was to convert the other way say: add r3, r5, r4. Would you know how i would go about converting those registers? would it be as simple as convert say r4 to 0100?

Comment: @jessie You need to go through the table, and remember that each register is represented by five bits. But basically yes.